# How to use the first path segment as a parameter in angular website

Tags: angular, routes

I have a simple angular application. The only function of the website is to load a configuration and set some images and links based on a name scraped from the first segment in the path. I have tried to set paths with no success in

```
const routes =
[
  { path: '*', component: MyComponent }
];
RouteModule.forRoot(routes).
```

The path is like https: //mydomain.com/codehere

MyComponent uses this code to get the path.

const locator = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();

The locator should = 'codehere'

I would like to parse the codehere part of the string and use it as the key to query my configuration data. It thought it was working locally but maybe not. I can now confirm that it works locally. I get 404 errors and no component is found.

I would expect it to work the same on the server

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a route like below where the first param will be available in the activated route, all you need to do is subscribe to it and perform your logic

home.ts

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Current Route Path</h1>
      <h3>Path: {{currentRouteParam}}</h3>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class HomeViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  currentRouteParam;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.currentRouteParam = params.path;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

app.routing.module

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginViewComponent } from './views/login/login.component';
import { HomeViewComponent } from './views/home/home.component';
import { CatalogViewComponent } from './views/catalog/catalog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginViewComponent, HomeViewComponent, CatalogViewComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: ':path', component: HomeViewComponent }]),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-srqg5i)